# Which FRINGE division is more advanced?

Tags: fringe

In the Television series, FRINGE, out of the two parallel universes, the original one and the one from where peter was stolen, which has a better FRINGE division in terms of awareness about the presence of parallel universes and other strange stuff.

Comment: Where are you in the series, and do you want spoilers?  The answer(s) do turn into plot points.

Comment: @IZkata I am in Season 4 Episode 12

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both universe had made progress in different directions. At first when alternate universe was introduced, it seemed like they were advanced. Though as the season progressed, they tried to pass the message that there were some innovations which were much more advance in the original (I'll refer as original universe for the universe where the season was started :) ) universe.

Comment: Can your provide an example of more advanced technologies in the prime universe

Answer (score 1):

The alternate side is more advanced in many areas.  I recall more than once where many inventions, like the cell phone, were brought from the alternate side to our side. Regarding the Fringe divisions, just look at the gear the alternate side uses!!

Answer (score 1):

It depends. The "Red" universe is a little bit more advanced when comes about technology because all of the breaktroughs that Waltern had to do in order to stop the destruction of their world and also to save his son.